What general concept, other than oriented volume, embodies all even (odd) permutations of $n$ elements?
Given an ordered orthogonal basis $v_1...v_k$ of a $k$-dimensional vector space, we can construct a $k$-vector in the geometric algebra over that space, simply by multiplying the basis vectors in the given order.  However, we can construct that same $k$-vector in the same way after re-ordering them via any even permutation.
In this sense, the concept of the $k$-vector, which is really that of oriented volume, embodies all permutations of a given parity, in a single mathematical object.
Is there another type of object, other than an oriented volume, that still has this property that it captures all even/odd permutations in a single object?  I also wouldn't count the alternating group $A_n$ here, since it includes them merely by definition.

The composition of a $k$-vector is much, much weaker than just "all even permutations of some vectors", since for instance $v\wedge w = (v+w)\wedge w$.

It's a little unclear exactly what you're after (and why), but the Vandermonde product of $n$ indeterminates is an object that in some sense captures even/odd-ness in that the permutations of the indeterminates which preserve/change its sign are precisely the even/odd ones.
